# When I `brew update` found the `https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/` not found

Tags: macos, homebrew

When I `brew update` found the `https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/` not found:

```
delo-MacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ brew --version
Homebrew 2.2.2
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 9e4997; last commit 2019-07-30)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 4b0e1; last commit 2019-12-27)
delo-MacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ brew update
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/' not found
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

- brew tap
- brew untap homebrew-dupes(If the result includes homebrew-dupes)
- brew update

Comment: `brew doctor` may also be helpful here.  See also: https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew/issues/701